# Do promises mess up functioning of Parse cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

Trying to debug some strange behavior in my Parse cloud functions.

I've been wondering if cloud functions that are expecting response.success() or response.error() to be called are guaranteed to wait until promises are resolved/error.

Here's an example:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("my_cloud_function", function(request, response) {
  myFunctionThatReturnsAPromise().then(function(msg) {
    msg = typeof msg !== 'undefined' ? msg : "";
    response.success(msg);
  }, function(error) {
    var message = typeof error.message !== 'undefined' ? error.message : "";
    response.error(message);
  });
});
```

This cloud function reaches the end of its execution before myFunctionThatReturnsAPromise() actually returns its promise and executes one of its then blocks. **Timeout aside, is my_cloud_function going to reliably set up the delivery of calls using the response object even after it finishes execution?**

It certainly seems like this is what I observe, but I'm not positive this behavior is guaranteed to happen consistently.

Comment: did you try 'return' in front of 'myFunction..'?  Then I believe it should wait until myFunction completes rather that just execute it.

Comment: No. `myFunctionThatReturnsAPromise` does definitely return the promise *before* the `function(request, response)` callback finishes to execute! Did you mean "*resolves its promise*"?

Comment: The example code in the "Writing a background job" section here *seems* to suggest the answer to my question is basically yes: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide

Comment: Bergi, I guess I mean, the end of the function is reached, and in its stack there is nothing left to do... so am I right in thinking that a Parse engine still spins, waiting for one of response's callback functions to be called?

Comment: aarosil - haven't tried that, can't find anything in the documentation to suggest that usage is supported.

Comment: BTW, you have one extra parenthesis `)` at the end of your code.

Comment: Thevs, there are 8 ('s and 8 )'s

Comment: @BenjaminWheeler: Yes, parse waits until the callbacks are called (or the [timeout occurs](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-resource)). Of course it doesn't necessarily *spin* (the CPU), it just sits there with the response object in memory and waits. And might even do other tasks in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that promises, as used in my code example, work fine. Parse waits until one of the response callbacks is called, even if it reaches the end of the invoking function's block, as long as there are outstanding callbacks or unresolved promises.